# Porting Java SE Game to Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

I'm learning to program in Java and would like to develop a mobile Chess game for the Blackberry platform.

It was recommended to me that, as a beginner, I should build the game for regular desktop use and avoid the more complex mobile development for now. I was told that I can port the game to Java ME once development in SE is complete.

My question is: is this really possible? What kinds of limitations exist between SE and ME that I should keep in mind while developing in SE?

I'd hate to have to go back and undo most of my work in order to get the game to work on my Blackberry.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure the advice is especially good.

The UI classes are different, so that part would have to be redone.  The UI would be a significant part of the work, so why do it twice?  Why learn the SE UI APIs if you *really* want to do J2ME?

There was an [SO question just yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1985360/are-all-j2se-classes-available-in-j2me) on the differences between J2SE and J2ME - that contains useful links for you.

If your aim is to very specifically target BlackBerry then why not [set up your development environment to deploy a 'Hello World' app](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/27869/0/page/1) to a BlackBerry simulator as your first step?  You might want to investigate RIMs own APIs as well as 'portable' J2ME classes as they will give you better integration with the device hardware (clickwheel and so on).

Comment: Great advice, Martin. And, thanks for the links. BTW, I had the 'Hello World' step in mind. However, now that I think about it, given that Java *is* platform independent, wouldn't it be best NOT to use RIM's APIs and, instead, go with a pure J2ME approach so that I can run the game in other platforms? I leaned towards Blackberry because that's the phone I currently have, but who's to say I won't switch over to an Android phone or something else tomorrow?

Comment: I agree.  You can always have 'optional' behaviour in your code or build that take advantage of hardware specific stuff like the BB clickwheel and add these later if needed and/or time permits.

Answer (score 2):

Java ME and Java SE both have same syntax. They both are Java, but they are not same. Actually they are **far far away** from being same.

Porting a Java SE (desktop) application to Java ME is as hard as porting a C# application to Java ME.

It is not just about GUI (GUI is totally different) many functions, methods Java SE has does not exists in Java ME.

Java ME does not even use **[JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jvm)**, it uses **[KVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_virtual_machine)**.

Write a simple hello world program in Java SE and then write the same for Java ME and you will see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

It is practically the same but you have to consider that a mobile doesn´t have same resources as a computer (memory, cpu, etc.) so you have to control more over this aspect.

You always will be able to download the Java ME platform and simulate your applications.

This is the website: [Java ME](http://java.sun.com/javame/downloads/sdk30.jsp)

Good luck!