# Convert Javase to javame

Tags: java, swing, java-me

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Porting Java SE Game to Java ME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987689/porting-java-se-game-to-java-me)

i write a a game with swing and java socket as my this semester java project at school ..our instructor said us that if you can write this code for mobiles i will give you extra points!now i dont know anything about j2me and i should write this extra project until  next 2 week and i don't know anything about j2me!(but i am strong at aspects of j2se very good).my question is converting code from swing and socket in j2se to j2me is very hard in other word can i do that in 2 week?
can you say me some good tourial about that?
thanks alot

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987689/porting-java-se-game-to-java-me

Comment: I think you're in big trouble, since rewriting from J2SE to J2ME is not trivial task and concerning Swing components - converting them to J2ME can be real nightmare

Comment: If you understand the working of swing nicely, then moving to J2ME won't be much of a problem. They are almost the same; the implementation the logic and everything else. The main point of difference is in the names of various components and methods. Most of the interdfaces are also same. Go ahead and you can easily complete your project in 2 weeks or less.

Answer (score 0):

Well ive had the same dilema before, i have a program on my computer that would be great as a mobile app but i thought it would take forever, but really theres not a lot of difference between the 2. They are both still java except android uses some XML to do layouts, which is very easy to do by the way. How long will it take you might ask? well it all depends on the app, if its a really complex app then it could take longer than 2 weeks, if its a simple app you could finish it by yourself in less than 1 week. If i was you i would go the extra mile and at least try it. Android is a very powerful tool and it is very easy to use if you know Object Oriented Programming well. Good Object Oriented Programming skills will make transferring your app a piece of cake. If you need any help at all with the conversion let me know but i think these tutorials should explain a lot to you:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/basics/what-is-android.html
- http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html
- http://developer.android.com/resources/browser.html?tag=sample (These are sample apps)

And you'll need to download eclipse and install a plugin. All of the information on how to install everything can be found here:

- http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

And heres the Eclipse Website where you can download the correct version:

- http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-classic-37/indigor

If you need any help whatsoever, send me an E-Mail and ill help you with whatever you need! Hope this helped!