# Converting from Java SE to Java ME

Tags: java, java-me

I have codes that runs in Java SE. I want to convert those so that I can run it via Java ME. How can I convert those codes from Java SE to Javca ME? Is there an easy way?

Comment: This question is **much** to broad to be answerable. Java SE and Java ME are (unfortunately) quite different beasts. So the topic in general could fill books. If you have a *specific* problem that you need help with, you can post here.

Answer (score 4):

Java ME is restricted to Java 1.3, so some of your code (for example, generics), may not work. Also, if you have a `Swing` GUI, that, obviously, will not work either.

In short: you need to redo your GUI and rewrite Java 1.3+ code.

Edit: I have little experience with Java ME, but the writer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987689/porting-java-se-game-to-java-me/1990986#1990986) answer states that it's in fact quite hard to port code from Java SE to Java ME.

Comment: Well, every Java ME that I ever touched didn't even have the Collections framework (only Vector and Hashtable) which was introduced in Java 1.2 (!)

Answer (score 0):

There's no real good way to do this in an automated fashion.  The quickest way is to try compiling your code for J2ME and seeing what doesn't compile.  From there fix it.  But Christiaan is right, it's basically 1.3 (no generics, no boxing, etc) and no swing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to do it directly using Java ME, since the coding style is different.

There is this tool-kit called  LWUIT, which is very similar to Swings. If you use that, with some time and effort, you will be able to port your application. You can find its tutorials and Documentation [here](http://lwuit.java.net/)